# Incorrect syntax in CASE statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am getting an error

> *Incorrect syntax near =*

while executing this procedure:

```
DECLARE @I_BRANCH_ID VARCHAR(MAX) 

EXEC GETBALANCE CASE WHEN @I_BRANCH_ID ='' THEN 0 ELSE @I_BRANCH_ID END
```

Comment: Please turn off your caps lock.

Comment: You've already asked this question - [How to use case in arguments of executing stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795625/how-to-use-case-in-arguments-of-executing-stored-procedure) - so please delete this copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put conditional syntax into an EXECUTE statement like this.

Instead, try:

```
IF (@I_BRANCH_ID = '')
    SET @I_BRANCH_ID = '0'

EXECUTE GetBalance @I_BRANCH_ID
```

Edit:

With more params, you can streamline to:

```
SELECT @param1 = CASE WHEN @param1 = '' THEN '0' ELSE @param1 END,
       @param2 = CASE WHEN @param2 = '' THEN '0' ELSE @param2 END,
       @param3 = CASE WHEN @param3 = '' THEN '0' ELSE @param3 END
       ... etc etc
```

Comment: ACTUALLY I HAVE TOO MANY NO OF ARGUMENTS I CANT USE IF I WANTS ONLY THORUGH CASE STATEMENT

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value of the variable separately from the EXECUTE statement:

```
DECLARE @I_BRANCH_ID VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @I_BRANCH_ID = CASE WHEN @I_BRANCH_ID = '' THEN 0 ELSE @I_BRANCH_ID END

EXEC GETBALANCE @I_BRANCH_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @I_BRANCH_ID VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @I_BRANCH_ID = CASE WHEN @I_BRANCH_ID = '' THEN '0' ELSE @I_BRANCH_ID END
EXEC GETBALANCE @I_BRANCH_ID
```